# Let $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2<1\}$ Prove S is a open set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Good night, i have a problem with this exercise:

Let $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+y^2<1\}$ Prove S is a open set.

Definition: A set is open if for all $a\in S$ exists $r>0$ such that $B(a,r)\subset S$

**My work:**

> Suppose $(x,y)\in S$. Let $r=1-d((0,0),(x,y))$ Then $B((x,y),r)\subset S$
>   
> For prove this, Suppose $(x',y')\in B((x,y),r)$ then $d((x',y'),(x,y))<r$
>   
>  That's implies $d((x',y'),(x,y))<1$

In this step i'm stuck, Can someone help me?

I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By triangle inequality,
\begin{align}d((x',y'),(0,0)) &\leq d((x',y'),(x,y))+d((0,0),(x,y))\\
& < r+ d((0,0),(x,y))\\
&=1−d((0,0),(x,y))+ d((0,0),(x,y))\\&=1\end{align}

Comment: Excellent. I understand you argument. But i have a little question., why if $d((x',y'),(0,0))<1$ then $(x',y') \in S$?

Comment: $d((x',y'),(0,0))=\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}<1$, hence $(x',y') \in S$ by definition of $S$.

Answer (score 4):

Your last step should actually be to conclude that $d((x',y'),(0,0)) < 1$, and to do that just apply the triangle inequality:
$$
d((x',y'),(0,0)) \le d((x',y'),(x,y)) + d((x,y),(0,0)) < r + (1-r) = 1.
$$