# Proof that $\{ (x,y) : x^2 + 2 y^2 < 1\}$ is an open set only using the definition.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following,

> $S = \{ (x,y) : x^2 + 2 y^2 < 1\}$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$

**My attempt**

Define (for convenience), $\partial S = \{ (x,y) : x^2 + 2 y^2 = 1\}$. Given $(x_0, y_0) \in S$, let $\delta = \min\{|(x, y) - (x_0, y_0)| : (x,y) \in \partial S\}$. Then $N((x_0, y_0), \delta) \subset S$.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, you're on the right track, but the main issue is that you haven't shown that $\delta>0$. This is more or less the point of the exercise.

Comment: It's because, for a given $(x_0,y_0)$, $\forall (x, y) \in \partial S$, $(x, y) \neq (x_0,y_0)$, thus this means $x \neq x_0$ or $y \neq y_0$, therefore $|(x,y) - (x_0, y_0)| = \sqrt{(x-x_0)^2 (y- y_0)^2} > 0$ ?

Comment: Somehow related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2476219/let-s-x-y-in-mathbbr2-x2y21-prove-s-is-a-open-set

Comment: Yes, you got that part. I forgot to say that you also need to somehow prove that $N((x_0,y_0), \delta) \subset S$. Of course this is intuitively obvious, but how would you prove it?

(This is why the other accepted answer is probably shorter and easier to write up, but since this is presumably a first analysis course it is a good exercise to try other approaches)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different approach: Define $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ by $f(x,y)=x^2+2y^2$.  $f$ is continuous.  Since $S=f^{-1}(-\infty, 1)$, and $(-\infty, 1)\subset\mathbb R$ is open, $S$ is open.

If you don't think this uses just the definition, let's go back to your approach. To show: $\delta \gt0$.  Suppose not.  Then there is a sequence $(x_n,y_n)\to (x_0,y_0)$ with $(x_n,y_n)\in\partial S\,\forall n$.  But $\partial S$ is closed (easy to see, since $\partial S=\bar S\cap\bar S^c$; or by using $f$ from above).  Thus $(x_0,y_0)\in\partial S$.  Contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

$S = \{ (x,y) : x^2 + 2 y^2 < 1\}$ is an set in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Geometrically, the set $S$ represents collection all points lying inside the ellipse (not on boundary) $x^2 + 2 y^2 = 1$.

Clearly it shows that every point in $S$ has atleast one neighborhood which is contained in the set $S$.

Thus $S$ is open.